# How to move to any given coordinates in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on moving functionality in forge viewer.I have tried different ways to achieve this but I couldn't able to do this. Note: coordinates are given. I just want to navigate or move to that coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use different methods on the `viewer.navigation` object, for example:

- [setView(position, target)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#setview-position-target) to move the camera to given position and orientation immediately
- `setTransitionRequest(state, pos, coi, fov, reorient, pivot)` to transition the camera to the new state over a short period of time. Here's what the different parameters mean:

  - `state: boolean` - value of the request, set to true in order to request the change of view.
  - `pos: THREE.Vector3` - the new camera position in world space
  - `coi: THREE.Vector3` - the point in world space that the camera should look towards.
  - `fov: number` - vertical field of view in degrees
  - `reorient: boolean` - set to true to recalculate up vector
  - `pivot: THREE.Vector3` - the new pivot point

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cant find setTransitionRequest method.

Comment: Yes :/ For some reason the auto-generated docs don't include this method. That's why I included the method signature here. We'll look into that.

Comment: Yes , you are right docs dont include this method but it also throws an error saying setTransitionRequest is not a function.

Comment: Sorry, it's `setRequestTransition`, not `setTransitionRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Petr's answer...

If you have lat-long position, in mind, then you can move the camera to that location, by converting from lat-long, to LMV model coordinate x,y,z position.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/GeolocationExtension/#lonlattolmv-lonlat

Once you have the x,y,z position, then use setView().

If you want a smoother camera movement (lerp) between multiple locations, then perhaps use this viewer.restoreState() technique with a slower duration.

Here's a demo:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/view-each-floor-using-vertical-explode

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped but now it is navigating to outer side of the model and I want to navigate to exact that point.Is there any problem of target?